# Simulating sliding in a div from left to right

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two divs which I want to simulate a slider but not actually use a slider, is it possible to use animate to simulate a div a sliding in from the right?

```
$('a.next').click(function(){
   $("#inside_work.part-one").hide();
   $("#inside_work.part-two").animate('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
});
```

Comment: You can try using  jQuery's animate function on the Div width. Set the beginning width to 0% & then animate it to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need is right here.

[JQuery Slide Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/)

```
    // click 
    $( "#inside_work.part-two" ).click(function() {
        //options and callback are optional
        var options = {};
        $("#inside_work.part-one").hide();
        $( "#effect" ).show( "hide", options, 500, callback );
        return false;
    });

    //callback function
    function callback() {
        //anything else you want to do here.
        //but completely optional
    };
```